# Spring Boot cannot return html file

Tags: html, spring-boot, templates, controller

[image]

[image]

[image]

Although I change `@Controller` to `@RestContoller`, it prints not `index.html` but `"index"`.

It should bring html file in templates folder but it doesn't work

I also tried to add some properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/templates
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

in application.properties and its still not working

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post images of code but just include the code with proper code tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Although I change `@Controller` to `@RestContoller`, it prints not `index.html` but `"index"`.

From the docs of `@RestController:

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

And from docs of `@ResponseBody`:

> Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body.

So changing the annotation to `@RestController` you indicate that the response body should be exactly the string you're returning, and Spring doesn't look for static files or templates.

It must be `@Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your pom contains thymeleaf dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Place the templates under `src/main/resources/templates` folder. The default extension is `.html`

**Make sure your controller has `@RequestMapping` annotation**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MainController {

  @GetMapping
  public String viewHomePage() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

**Remove all configurations from `application.properties`**